# What is a cluster in a RDBMS?

Tags: rdbms

Please explain what a cluster is in a RDBMS?

Comment: Are you referring to a cluster of servers, or a clustered index? The below two answers describe a cluster of servers.

Answer (score 3):

In **SQL**, a cluster can also refer to a specific physical ordering of rows.

For example, consider a database with two tables: INVOICES and INVOICE_ITEMS. If many INVOICE_ITEMs are inserted concurrently, chances are that items of the same invoice end up on multiple physical blocks of the underlying storage. When reading such an invoice, unneeded data will be read together with the interesting rows. Clustering INVOICE_ITEMS over the foreign key to INVOICES groups rows of items the same invoice together in the same block, thus reducing the amount of necessary read operations when accessing the invoice.

Read about [clustered index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Clustered) on wikipedia.

---

In **system administration**, a "cluster" is a number of servers configured to provide the same service, but look like one server to the users.

This can be done for performance reasons (two servers can answer more requests than a single one) or redundancy (if one server crashes, the others still work).

Such configurations often need special software or setup to work. Some services, like serving static web content, can be clustered very easily. Others, like RDBMS, need complicated replication schemes to coordinate.

Read about [computer clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(computing)) on wikipedia.

---

In **statistics**, a cluster is a "group of items so that objects from the same cluster are more similar to each other than objects from different clusters."

Read about [Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) on wikipedia.

Comment: when talking about RDBMS's, clustering is almost always for availability.

Comment: @Mitch: of course not. concepts like sharding are exact opposite of redundancy. Using DB clusters is principally about load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster):

> High-availability clusters (also known
>   as HA Clusters or Failover Clusters)
>   are computer clusters that are
>   implemented primarily for the purpose
>   of providing high availability of
>   services which the cluster provides.
>   They operate by having redundant
>   computers or nodes which are then used
>   to provide service when system
>   components fail. Normally, if a server
>   with a particular application crashes,
>   the application will be unavailable
>   until someone fixes the crashed
>   server. HA clustering remedies this
>   situation by detecting
>   hardware/software faults, and
>   immediately restarting the application
>   on another system without requiring
>   administrative intervention, a process
>   known as Failover

Answer (score 1):

In database context it can have two completely different meanings:

- may either mean [data clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering) or [index clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Clustered), which is grouping of similar rows. This is useful for data mining, some databases (e.g. [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_index_clustering_factor.htm)) also use it to optimize physical data organization;
- or [cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) as database running on many closely linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering, in the context of databases.
It refers to the ability of several servers or instances to connect to a single database.
An instance is the collection of memory and processes that interacts with a database, which is the set of physical files that actually store data.